# Mixed Type Typescript Validation with AJV

Tags: json, typescript, validation, ajv

[image]So I'm trying to use Ajv npm package to validate JSON against our typescript types as a single source of truth. I have this 99% working for multiple types/checks, but am running into a small issue with a specific mixed type. Initially I tried to reduce the examples, but it was invalid so I included the entire type (the issue is with `defaultValue` specifically in `ModuleJsonSectionInput` type marked both as `THIS ONE`). The only workaround I have found is to place `as any` at the end of the schema which negates the single source of truth approach I'm trying to take. Any insight would be super appreciated!

I'm using 8.12.0 version of Ajv.

Typescript Types

```
type InputType = 'input' | 'dropdown' | 'multiselect' | 'textarea' | 'richtext' | 'code-editor' | 'section-break' | 'toggle';

type Condition = 'equalTo' | 'greaterThan' | 'lessThan' | 'greaterThanOrEqualTo' | 'lessThanOrEqualTo' | 'notEqualTo' | 'falsey';

interface InputValue {
  label: string;
  value: string;
}

interface ModuleJsonSections {
  collapsed?: boolean;
  inputs: ModuleJsonSectionInput[];
  label: string;
}

interface ConditionalRenderConfig {
  targetValueName: string;
  condition: Condition;
  compareValue: string | number | boolean;
}

interface ModuleJsonWebhookConfig {
  method: string;
  url: string;
  headers?: Record<string, string>;
  body?: Record<string, unknown> | string;
  isSearchOnly?: boolean;
}

interface ModuleJsonWebhookConfigValuesResponse extends ModuleJsonWebhookConfig {
  responsePath: string;
  labelPath: string;
  valuePath: string;
}

interface ModuleJsonSectionInput {
  label: string;
  name: string;
  type: InputType;
  subtype?: string;
  valuesType: 'static' | 'api';
  values?: InputValue[];
  allowFreeInput?: boolean;
  api?: ModuleJsonWebhookConfigValuesResponse;
  defaultValue?: string | boolean | number | string[]; // THIS ONE
  conditionalRenderConfig?: ConditionalRenderConfig;
}
```

Javascript Schema that works but throws a Typescript error

```
export const sectionsSchema: JSONSchemaType<ModuleJsonSections[]> = {
  type: "array",
  default: [],
  items: {
    type: "object",
    required: [
      "label",
      "inputs"
    ],
    properties: {
      label: {
        type: "string"
      },
      inputs: {
        type: "array",
        items: {
          type: "object",
          required: [
            "label",
            "name",
            "type",
            "valuesType",
          ],
          properties: {
            label: {
              type: "string"
            },
            name: {
              type: "string"
            },
            type: {
              enum: [ "input", "dropdown", "multiselect", "textarea", "richtext", "code-editor", "section-break", "toggle" ],
              type: "string"
            },
            subtype: {
              type: "string",
              nullable: true,
            },
            valuesType: {
              enum: [ "static", "api" ],
              type: "string"
            },
            values: {
              type: "array",
              nullable: true,
              default: [],
              items: {
                type: "object",
                required: [
                  "label",
                  "value"
                ],
                properties: {
                  label: {
                    type: "string",
                  },
                  value: {
                    type: "string",
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            allowFreeInput: {
              type: "boolean",
              nullable: true,
            },
            api: {
              type: "object",
              nullable: true,
              required: [
                "responsePath",
                "labelPath",
                "valuePath",
                "method",
                "url",
              ],
              properties: {
                responsePath: {
                  type: "string"
                },
                labelPath: {
                  type: "string"
                },
                valuePath: {
                  type: "string"
                },
                method: {
                  type: "string"
                },
                url: {
                  type: "string"
                },
                headers: {
                  type: "object",
                  required: [],
                  nullable: true
                },
                body: {
                  type: "object",
                  required: [],
                  nullable: true
                },
                isSearchOnly: {
                  type: "boolean",
                  nullable: true
                },
              },
            },
            defaultValue: { // THIS ONE
              oneOf: [
                {
                  type: "array",
                  nullable: true,
                  items: {
                    type: "string",
                  },
                },
                {
                type:[
                    "string",
                    "boolean",
                    "integer",
                  ],
                  nullable: true,
                },
              ],
            },
            conditionalRenderConfig: {
              type: "object",
              nullable: true,
              required: [
                "targetValueName",
                "condition",
                "compareValue"
              ],
              properties: {
                targetValueName: {
                  type: "string"
                },
                condition: {
                  type: "string",
                  enum: [ "equalTo", "greaterThan", "lessThan", "greaterThanOrEqualTo", "lessThanOrEqualTo", "notEqualTo", "falsey", ],
                },
                compareValue: {
                  type: [ "string", "integer", "boolean" ],
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      collapsed: {
        type: "boolean",
        nullable: true,
      }
    }
  }
};
```

TypeScript Error

```
Type '{ type: "array"; default: never[]; items: { type: "object"; required: ("label" | "inputs")[]; properties: { label: { type: "string"; }; inputs: { type: "array"; items: { type: "object"; required: ("type" | "label" | "name" | "valuesType")[]; properties: { ...; }; }; }; collapsed: { ...; }; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'JSONSchemaType<ModuleJsonSections[]>'.
  Types of property 'items' are incompatible.
    Type '{ type: "object"; required: ("label" | "inputs")[]; properties: { label: { type: "string"; }; inputs: { type: "array"; items: { type: "object"; required: ("type" | "label" | "name" | "valuesType")[]; properties: { ...; }; }; }; collapsed: { ...; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'UncheckedJSONSchemaType<ModuleJsonSections, false>'.
      The types of 'properties.inputs' are incompatible between these types.
        Type '{ type: "array"; items: { type: "object"; required: ("type" | "label" | "name" | "valuesType")[]; properties: { label: { type: "string"; }; name: { type: "string"; }; type: { enum: ("input" | "dropdown" | ... 5 more ... | "toggle")[]; type: "string"; }; ... 6 more ...; conditionalRenderConfig: { ...; }; }; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ $ref: string; } | (UncheckedJSONSchemaType<ModuleJsonSectionInput[], false> & { nullable?: false | undefined; const?: ModuleJsonSectionInput[] | undefined; enum?: readonly ModuleJsonSectionInput[][] | undefined; default?: ModuleJsonSectionInput[] | undefined; })'.
          Types of property 'items' are incompatible.
            Type '{ type: "object"; required: ("type" | "label" | "name" | "valuesType")[]; properties: { label: { type: "string"; }; name: { type: "string"; }; type: { enum: ("input" | "dropdown" | "multiselect" | "textarea" | "richtext" | "code-editor" | "section-break" | "toggle")[]; type: "string"; }; ... 6 more ...; conditionalR...' is not assignable to type 'UncheckedJSONSchemaType<ModuleJsonSectionInput, false>'.
              The types of 'properties.defaultValue' are incompatible between these types.
                Type '{ oneOf: ({ type: "array"; nullable: boolean; items: { type: "string"; }; } | { type: ("string" | "boolean" | "integer")[]; nullable: boolean; })[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ $ref: string; } | (UncheckedJSONSchemaType<string | number | boolean | string[] | undefined, false> & { nullable: true; const?: null | undefined; enum?: readonly (string | ... 4 more ... | undefined)[] | undefined; default?: string | ... 4 more ... | undefined; })'.
                  Type '{ oneOf: ({ type: "array"; nullable: boolean; items: { type: "string"; }; } | { type: ("string" | "boolean" | "integer")[]; nullable: boolean; })[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ type: "array"; items: UncheckedJSONSchemaType<string, false>; contains?: UncheckedPartialSchema<string> | undefined; minItems?: number | undefined; ... 4 more ...; additionalItems?: undefined; } & { ...; } & { ...; } & { ...; }'.
                    Type '{ oneOf: ({ type: "array"; nullable: boolean; items: { type: "string"; }; } | { type: ("string" | "boolean" | "integer")[]; nullable: boolean; })[]; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ type: "array"; items: UncheckedJSONSchemaType<string, false>; contains?: UncheckedPartialSchema<string> | undefined; minItems?: number | undefined; ... 4 more ...; additionalItems?: undefined; }': type, itemsts(2322)
```

Comment: The schema you shared isn't valid javascript.

Comment: I've updated it to include the entire type and marked the relevant issue with `THIS ONE`

Comment: I've validated your Schema against the JSON schema schema (no typo), and I'm not getting any errors. This suggests to me that the types you use might be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this! When I checked my code the typescript error is still there which means the types do not align with the schema validation (they align for all the other one's I've done and generate no errors on those). I've included a screenshot of the original problem to show that + updated the typescript error to show the entire error message in case other parts were relevant!

Comment: Does the error still happen if you remove `<ModuleJsonSections[]>`? If yes this suggest there's a bug in JSONSchemaType

Comment: If I remove the generic type `<ModuleJsonSections[]>` from `JSONSchemaType<ModuleJsonSections[]>` it throws the following typescript error: `Generic type 'JSONSchemaType' requires 1 type argument(s)` which makes sense because it needs a type argument to validate against. If I remove that `JSONSchemaType<ModuleJsonSections[]>` there is no error, but I lose the ability to type against the TypeScript type in our system.

The parser is getting confused because the type is `string | boolean | number | string[]; ` and there cannot be items/children of `string | boolean | number` unlike `string[]`.

Comment: I'm just trying to determine if the issue is in your type `ModuleJsonSection` or `JSONSchemaType`, so maybe placing `any` there would also be interesting. One thing that stands out from reading your types is that several are `nullable`, yet `ModuleJsonSection` does not allow `null` in many of these places.

Comment: If the issue is indeed in `ModuleJsonSection` and you can't exactly pinpoint it, I would suggest you drastically simplify the type and slowly add more properties until you hit the issue. The errors are incredibly hard to read so it's hard to just eye it.

Comment: Yeah, if I comment out the `defaultValue` marked with `THIS ONE` and comment out the corresponding schema marked with `THIS ONE`, the typescript types pass, the validation works, and there are no errors. So I'm 100% certain it's within those sections marked `THIS ONE`.